# List of encrypted triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to get the list of encrypted triggers in database?
Actually, as I see, for encrypted trigger in the sys.sql_modules, the column definition is NULL. But may be exist another way to determine is trigger encrypted or not, using system views or other internal database info?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`OBJECTPROPERTYEX`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188390.aspx) function to query for the `IsEncrypted` property. E.g.

```
select * from sys.objects
where OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id,'IsEncrypted') = 1
and OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id,'IsTrigger') = 1
```

Comment: @YuriyVelichko - I've not been able to find anything obvious in a 5 minute search. Annoying.